# Numpy function argument confussion list or tuple

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I am new to numpy and I keep getting confused in arguments passing, some times its list and some times tuple, like this https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

```
numpy.vstack(tup)
```

doc says it takes tuple, but if I pass list it also works

```
np.vstack((c1, c2))
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

and with list its the same output

```
np.vstack([c1, c2])
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

Comment: Whats the issue? It says the name of the parameter is tup, but the type is sequence of arrays. Both the tuple and the list are sequence.

Comment: The docs actually says "sequence of ndarrays".  That's a general term that includes tuple, list, even an array.  Often list and tuple work equally well.  `numpy` has a couple of cases there it treats them differently, notably when indexing, and one inputs to structured arrays.  But those are the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hpaulj correctly says, the input parameter is just named `tup` but `tup` just has to be a *sequence* of np.arrays.

A sequence can be things like a tuple, array, pandas.Series etc.

If it has to be *only* a tuple it would be stated as such i.e "tup: tuple" and not "tup: sequence" in the docs